# Calculate random numbers

Tags: c#

I've made a simple program where a user decides how many numbers will be used in the program.

The program then generates the amount of numbers randomly. How do I calculate those random numbers together?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int amountOfNumbers;
        int counter = 0;
        int randomNumbers = 0;
        int calcRandomNumbers;

        Random generateRandNums = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(generateRandNums.Next(5,29));

        Console.WriteLine("\nHow many numbers do you want to be entered?");
        amountOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (counter < amountOfNumbers) {
            counter++;
            Console.Write(generateRandNums.Next(20) + ", ");
        }

        randomNumbers = generateRandNums.Next(20);
        calcRandomNumbers = +randomNumbers;
        Console.WriteLine("The final sum is " + calcRandomNumbers);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep generated numbers and then sum they or increment immediately a current sum by generated number.

Comment: You add your random generated number to another `sum` variable and use that.

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand the question... Do you want parallel execution?

Comment: Basically I just want to add together the generated random numbers. So if the following 3 random numbers (5, 2, 1) are generated, I would then want to calculate them (5+2+1) and get the result.

Comment: @FabioLolli I am having the same problem as you. I feel the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sum in the while-loop, not outside:

```
while (counter < amountOfNumbers) {
    counter++;
    int randomNumber = generateRandNums.Next(20);
    calcRandomNumbers += randomNumber;
    Console.Write(randomNumber + ", ");
}
```

You could also store all numbers in a `List<int>` and then use `list.Sum()`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a slight modification. Edit: don't know how to input the below into a code format. 
`while (counter < amountOfNumbers) {`
 
`counter++; int randomNumber = generateRandNums.Next(20);` `Console.Write(randomNumber + ", ");`
`sum += randomNumber; }`
`Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var list = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++) 
      list.Add(generateRandNums.Next(20));

    calcRandomNumbers = list.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks you miss some code arrangements make me confused why you use **calcRandomNumbers = +randomNumbers;** out of while clause if you want sum.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int amountOfNumbers;
        int counter = 0;
        int randomNumbers = 0;
        int calcRandomNumbers=0;

        Random generateRandNums = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(generateRandNums.Next(5, 29));

        Console.WriteLine("\nHow many numbers do you want to be entered?");
        amountOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (counter < amountOfNumbers)
        {
            counter++;
            randomNumbers = generateRandNums.Next(20);
            Console.Write(randomNumbers + ", ");
            calcRandomNumbers = +randomNumbers;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The final sum is " + calcRandomNumbers);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```